# never would v would never

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Does it make a difference which comes first:

"I ***never would*** have thought that someone was going to come to kill him".

and

"I ***would never*** have thought that someone was going to come to kill him".

Answer (score 1):

No.

You also you can say I *would have **never*** thought.

However, localized English may mean in some regions/periods of time, one is/was more prevalently used than the other.